# Can I name a Node with a variable that is in a String array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to create a node and name it with a string that I stored in a string array, but it won't accept it. Is there a way to do this?

```
String strLine;
while ((strLine = br2.readLine()) != null)   {
    String[] arr=strLine.split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
        String v = arr[i];
        Node arr[i] =  new Node(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Node`? What error are you getting?

Comment: You can always add a `name` field to your Node class and store a name there.  You can define things so that that name can be sorted, used as the key in a Map or Set, etc.

Comment: This is invalid: `Node arr[i] =  new Node(v);`.  You must allocate an array before you store anything into it.  (And you can't name two different things with the same name in the same context.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, it helped me a lot fixing my program and make it work 
what i did is creating a vertex constructor and then just check if there is a node with the same name if not add new node.

```
      String strLine;
          while ((strLine = br2.readLine()) != null)   {
          String[] arr=strLine.split(",");

          for (int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
                String v = arr[i];
                String w = arr[++i];
                double weight =Double.parseDouble(arr[++i]);
                if(S.findVertexByName(v) == false)
                {


                    S.addVertex(new Vertex(v));
                    count ++;
                }
                 if(S.findVertexByName(w) == false)
                {


                    S.addVertex(new Vertex(w));
                    count ++;
                }

                S.addEdge(S.getVertexByName(v), S.getVertexByName(w), weight);
               }             
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the value of a variable (or an array element) as a variable name in Java. The best you can do is create a `Map<String, Node>` to serve as a symbol table:

```
String strLine;
Map<String, Node> nodeMap = new HashMap<String, Node>();
while ((strLine = br2.readLine()) != null)   {
    String[] arr=strLine.split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
        String v = arr[i];
        nodeMap.put(v, new Node(v));
    }
}
```

Then later you can retrieve a `Node` by name.

```
Node n = nodeMap.get("some name");
```